# List of peers not shared in private network

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

I have a simplified version of a private network I need to build. This is done with `parity v1.6.8`

There is one mining node that is used as a bootstrap node, let's call it `B`.
Then first not-mining node `N1` joins the network by connecting to `B` via `bootnodes` parameter. I see that blocks are imported and that each one of them have 1 peer now. That is as expected.

Now add another not-mining node `N2`, it also connects to `B`. `B` now has 2 peers, however `N1` and `N2` still only have 1 peer each. If I stop `B`, `N1` and `N2` will lose connection and have 0 peers. This seems to be incorrect. I can use json-rpc and manually call `addReservedPeer` to add `N2` to `N1` and it works - each node has 2 peers now.

If later a third node `N3` joins the network it again gets only 1 peer, `B` has 2+1=3 peers, `N1` and `N2` still have 2 peers each. Now if I add `N2` to `N3` via rpc call, they will connect to each other, however `N1` still won't be connected to `N3`, although `N2` and `N1` were explicitly connected on the previous step.

Each node is run from docker container on Azure VM. Ports are forwarded by `docker run -p`. I specify the actual public IP address of a node in `network.nat`.

Here is config.toml from `B`:

```
[parity]
chain = "spec.json"
base_path = "parity"
[network]
nat="extip:<B-public-IP>"
port = 30300
discovery=true
[rpc]
cors = "all"
interface = "0.0.0.0"
hosts = ["all"]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[account]
password = ["node.pwd"]
[mining]
force_sealing = true
engine_signer = "0xabcdef..."
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

`N1`, `N2`, `N3` share the same config.toml except for public IP in `network.nat`

```
[parity]
chain = "spec.json"
base_path = "parity"
[network]
nat="extip:<N-public-ip>"
bootnodes=["enode://012345...@<B-public-ip>:30300"]
port = 30300
discovery=true
[rpc]
cors = "all"
interface = "all"
hosts = ["all"]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
```

seems like I've enabled everything...

Since I can remotely call rpc, say from `N1` and add peer to `N2` it seems like all necessary ports are open and accessible, although if I call `netPeers` to get a list of peers of a node, they are returned with both public and private ips:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "active": 0,
        "connected": 1,
        "max": 25,
        "peers": [{
            "caps": ["eth/62", "eth/63", "par/1", "par/2"],
            "id": "<enode id here>",
            "name": "Parity/v1.6.8-beta-c396229-20170608/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.18.0",
            "network": {
                "localAddress": "172.17.0.2:40286",
                "remoteAddress": "<public IP>:30300"
            },
            "protocols": {
                "eth": {
                    "difficulty": null,
                    "head": "81054935d40ed7ffd94a7f4915f52c96fe0ebfe42ee715df0fa0decb76d70c45",
                    "version": 2
                },
                "les": null
            }
        }]
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

Please advise, am I missing something in config files or how can I double check network configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have also forwarded udp port 30300: `docker run -p 30300:30300 -p 30300:30300/udp ...`

Comment: Are you answering your own question?  Or do you mean to Edit your question?

Comment: i'm answering my own question. I can't accept it in 22 hours...